# querying amplify graphql many-to-many relationship

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm exploring amplify with typescript by making a library and have set up a many-to-many connection

```
type Book @model {
  # ! means non-null GraphQL fields are allowed to be null by default
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  picture: String!
  genres: [BookGenre] @connection(keyName: "byBook", fields: ["id"])
  createdAt: String!
  userId: String!
}

type BookGenre
@model(queries: null)
@key(name: "byBook", fields: ["bookID", "genreID"])
@key(name: "byGenre", fields: ["genreID", "bookID"]) {
  id: ID!
  bookID: ID!
  genreID: ID!
  book: Book! @connection(fields: ["bookID"])
  genre: Genre! @connection(fields: ["genreID"])
}

type Genre @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  createdAt: String!
  books: [BookGenre] @connection(keyName: "byGenre", fields: ["id"])
}
```

I can create a new book and add the user provided genres like this

```
const handleSubmit = async (evt) => {
        evt.preventDefault();
        const createdAt = new Date().toISOString();
        const bookID = hash(name);
        const book: CreateBookInput = {
            id: bookID,
            name,
            picture: "",
            createdAt: createdAt,
            userId: "faked"
        };
        try {
            await API.graphql(
                graphqlOperation(createBook, {
                    input: book
                })
            );
            for (const t of tags) {
                const genreID = hash(t)
                const genre: CreateGenreInput = {
                    id: genreID, name: t, createdAt
                }
                await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createGenre, {input: genre}))

                const bookGenre: CreateBookGenreInput = {
                    bookID, genreID
                }
                await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createBookGenre, {input: bookGenre}))
            }

            setName("")
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
        }
    }
```

This might not be the best way to do it! As it is many writes for each book but I can see the genres and their join records being written to Dynamo

I want to load a page that lists all of the books.

I've done this by:

```
    let result;
    try {
        result = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listBooks));
    } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
        return { props: { books: [] }};
    }
    if (result.errors) {
        console.warn("Failed to fetch books. ", result.errors);
        return { props: { books: [] }};
    }
    
    const queryResult: ListBooksQuery = result.data
    if (queryResult.listBooks !== null) {
        let books = queryResult.listBooks.items
        return { props: { books }};
    }

    return { props: { books: [] }};
```

But this doesn't load the genres...

I'm guessing I need to query through `@key(name: "byBook", fields: ["bookID", "genreID"])` but I'm not understanding how to do that by looking at the generated code...

I'm new to amplify and to graphql so am assuming I'm missing something trivial :)

What's the correct way to query for a list of all items and their children through a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Having the same problem despite the docs (https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/connection#many-to-many-connections) saying, I 'just' need to invoke `Book.genres`. Frustrating.

Comment: At the time of insertion of data

`const bookGenre: CreateBookGenreInput = {     bookID, genreID   }`
Why you are not providing  BookGenre ID?

Comment: Also, the GraphQL connection at creation time asks how many levels deep you need the connection can you double-check if there you have the value 2 or <2 there?

Answer (score 0):

It seems `amplify` does not correctly generate the queries.

I assume your generated query looks something like this:

```
export const listBooks = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListBooks(
    $filter: ModelBookFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listBooks(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        name
        picture
        genres {
          nextToken
        }
        createdAt
        userId
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`;
```

In order to load the `Genre` as well, you need to modify the query to:

```
export const listBooks = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListBooks(
    $filter: ModelBookFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listBooks(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        name
        picture
        genres {
          items {
            genre {
              name
            }
          }
          nextToken
        }
        createdAt
        userId
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`;
```

`genres.items` will load all the entities from the join table.
`genre` will then load the field on the entity, which references the `Genre` table.